# Package chemmacros changes \textbullet

Tags: beamer, fonts, chemmacros

The following document produces a weird shaped `\textbullet`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\sfdefault{hlcn}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\Huge
\textbullet
\end{document}
```

[image]

Commenting out the `chemmacros` package, or the `\sfdefault` change produce a regular rounded one:

[image]

and I thought this was the Lucida Casual font... What is going on?

Comment: Try  `\usepackage[expert]{lucidabr}`

Comment: Tried it... no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of what I get from the font table of `hlcrn8c` (the font used for font encoding TS1, family `hlcn`, series `m` and shape `n`):

[image]

The bullet corresponds to `\char"88` (octal `´210`). So it's a precise choice by Bigelow and Holmes.

I get the same with or without `chemmacros` (but as I don't have the obsolete `lucidabr` package, I used `lucimatx`).

You get a round bullet by undeclaring the association of `\textbullet` with `TS1`

```
\documentclass[noamssymb]{beamer}
\usepackage{lucimatx} % noamssymb is necessary with lucimatx
\renewcommand\sfdefault{hlcn}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\UndeclareTextCommand\textbullet{TS1}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault\textbullet{$\bullet$}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\Huge
\textbullet
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Without Lucida packages:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{hlcn}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \UndeclareTextCommand\textbullet{TS1}%
  \DeclareTextCommandDefault\textbullet{$\bullet$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\Huge
\textbullet
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I get the same "problem" behaviour without any lucida package, just with `\def\sfdefault{hlcn}`. Could it be my font installation is old/broken? But still, loading `chemmacros`makes a difference

Comment: @Jellby What `chemmacros` does is to enable TS1. When it is enabled, the bullet is taken from the TS1 font, so the one in the picture.

Comment: And how would I enable the "curly" `\textbullet` without `chemmacros`? I can't just use `\usepackage[TS1]{fontenc}`...

Comment: @Jellby `\usepackage{textcomp}`